# Execute Oracle Stored Proc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle stored proc with signiture: (part of package: Contractor)

```
PROCEDURE usp_sel_contractors(g_contractors OUT sel_contractor);
```

I am trying to execute it like:

```
execute Contractor.usp_sel_contractors;
```

I'm used to MSSqlServer. This seems like it should be strait forward.

I keep getting error:

```
Invalid Sql Statement
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is "sel_contractor" - a ref cursor?

Comment: no its a user stored procedure. part of a package called Contractor. `execute Contractor.usp_sel_contractors` also has the same effect

Comment: No, I was asking about "sel_contractor", not "usp_sel_contractor" - the word following "OUT".

Comment: ooooooo my bad. :-P `TYPE sel_contractor IS REF CURSOR;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming sel_contractor is a ref cursor type, you could do this in SQL Plus:

```
var rc refcursor

exec usp_sel_contractors(:rc)

print rc
```

Comment: You say I can do it in sql plus, is there a way to do this in sql developer?

Comment: Yes, that works in SQL Developer too - I just tried it.  Use the "run script" button.

Comment: I tried: `var rc refcursor  exec Contractor.usp_sel_contractors(:rc)  print rc` and got no results but under script output It says: `Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | REFCURSOR |
BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]`

Comment: Nope, that was it. Thanks. I just don't unstand why I can't get the results of the stored proc to show up in the nice results grid like the results of a regular query. MsSqlServer does it so easily...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd be getting that specific error message, but the obvious problem is that the procedure has a parameter and you're not passing one.  Since it's an OUT parameter you would need to pass a variable of the appropriate type which will be populated by the procedure.

For example:

```
DECLARE
  my_contractors  sel_contractor;
BEGIN
  usp_sel_contractors( my_contractors );

  // Do something with the contents of my_contractors here
END;
/
```

Comment: ugh. alright thanks. Leave it to Oracle to make this complicated. I just want to output the results? How do I do that?